# How to configure dispatcher to redirect to home page when session is null or timed out

Tags: spring

I am using Spring Mvc 3.x version. I don't want to write a if check on every single page. Instead, i need the code that is supported in Spring internally

Comment: Use a servlet `Filter` which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is the best suit for this kind of use case. You can intercept every request and check if there is an active session

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        if (session == null) {   //checking whether the session exists
            this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/loginPage.html");
        } else {
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //close any resources here
    }
}
```

This example has been taken from https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/session-management-in-java-using-servlet-filters-and-cookies-7c536b40448f. Check the article for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter in web.xml like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.java.util.SessionFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>/Page1.htm</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The Filter implementation could be like -

```
    public class FilterTest implements Filter {
    ...

    private ArrayList<String> urlList;    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            String url = request.getServletPath();
            boolean allowedRequest = false;
            if (urlList.contains(url)) {
                allowedRequest = true;
            }

            if (!allowedRequest) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                if (null == session) {
                    response.sendRedirect("startup.jsp");
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
            String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");
            urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                urlList.add(token.nextToken());

            }
}
```